# Can I perform a certain task based on a view controller's identifier?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, identifier

I was wondering if I could run some lines of code only if the identifier of the class is (for example) "hello". If so, how do I check this? Is it something like the following?

```
if (firstInterfaceController.identifier == @"hello")
{
    // perform some lines of code
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically, yes...though there are definitely better ways to achieve what you are trying to do. Depending on the complexity, you might want to create a child class that inherits from the parent `firstInterfaceController`. Or, you could check other variables that are not dependent on the view.

Comment: I've got 20+ view controllers in storyboard (each with identifiers 1, 2, 3, etc), and I'd like to do all the work for it within one class and just do `if identifier = 1 then... (1 line of code)` `if identifier = 2 then... (1 line of code)`. What's the best way to do that? I don't want to make 20+ class files and do the same thing in each.

Comment: Correct, you definitely don't want to create 20+ class files that do the same thing. If it's executing a few lines of code, you could put it in a switch case for identifier, executing the few lines of code for each case. If multiple identifiers execute the same code, you can do something like `case 3 ... 6` and execute the same code for multiple identifiers.

Comment: How would I make a switch case for the identifier?

Comment: Similar to how you have `if (identifier = 1)` just create a switch case. `identifier` may not be the best to use. For example, you could also do a switch on the view tag. In either case it would be something like: 
`switch (identifier) 
case 0:
// code;
break;
default;
break;`

Add as many cases as you have identifiers.

Comment: Yes, I was going to do that, but I don't know how you setup the identifier. Am I supposed to do `firstInterfaceController.identifier`?

Comment: If identifier is an int, then yes. Otherwise, create some other int @property or set a tag and switch on that.

Comment: I mean, how do I connect the identifier property from storyboard to the class file?

Comment: In that case, then yes, `firstInterfaceController.identifier` is what you want.

Comment: When I type that in, it says `Property 'identifier' not found on object of type 'firstInterfaceController'`